# Why am I unable to use using SixLabors ImageSharp?

Tags: nuget

For some reason whenever I try to install SixLabors using the Nuget Package Manager or Console, after it succeeds I am unable to do `using SixLabors.ImageSharp;` SixLabors doesn't even show up in the Intellisense menu. I'm running SDK 7.0.4 while SixLabors supports .NET Standard 2.0+ and to my knowledge that means it's compatible with .NET 7.0.4.

I've tried creating a new Console App (.NET Framework) then using both the NuGet manager, and the NuGet console, but both times I'm still unable to do `using SixLabors.ImageSharp;`. It's installing successfully I'm just unable to access the namespace. How do I get this to work? Does it not support .NET 7 or am I installing it wrong?

Comment: Is it showing up under your project References?

Comment: Nope it's not @mxmissile

Comment: Something is missing here, you dont get any errors or warnings when you install it via nuget?

Comment: Nope, I've also tried doing it on a new console app, but nothing happened. I was able to install OpenTK just fine using NuGet, and it's now under references, but nothing for SixLabors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3.0.0+ now only has support for net6.0, not .NET Framework. Versions 2.1.4 and under have support for .NET Framework. You can check this under Dependencies when using NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (reinstalling the package or editing csproj file didn't help) then I downgraded the package to v2.1.4 and the issue resolved. Maybe this helps someone.